# What is a narrow prototype and why would I need one?

Tags: c, function-prototypes

While compiling xterm I came across a configure option named

```
--enable-narrowproto    enable narrow prototypes for X libraries
```

(The negation of this option is required to make the scrollbar work under Cygwin, along with `--disable-imake`.)

I know that in K&R C prototypes didn't exist and all arguments smaller than `int` or `double` underwent promotions. Searching the ISO C99 Standard came up empty. What exactly is a *narrow* prototype? Is there a *wide* prototype for symmetry? What potential problem arises if I don't use a narrow prototype?

Comment: What did searching though `xterm`'s sources and Makefiles revealed?

Comment: Did you read the `INSTALL` file in `xterm`'s source code?

Comment: @alk A lot of autoconf/configure/imake mystery. It sets the -DNARROWPROTO macro unused by xterm. So it must be an X thing.

Comment: Just guessing: "*norrow*" might refer to "*norrowing down*" the *number* of prototypes, not the prototypes them selfs.

Comment: Another, propably more realistic, guess is that *narrow/wide* refers to the size of certain types of X.

Comment: @alk the second guess is correct, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `NARROWPROTO` macro is used in `Xfuncproto.h` to define another macro

```
#ifdef NARROWPROTO
#define NeedWidePrototypes 0
#else
#define NeedWidePrototypes 1        /* default to make interropt. easier */
#endif
```

`NeedWidePrototypes` which is in turn used in `Xlib.h` for example in the following way

```
extern XModifierKeymap  *XInsertModifiermapEntry(
    XModifierKeymap*    /* modmap */,
#if NeedWidePrototypes
    unsigned int    /* keycode_entry */,
#else
    KeyCode     /* keycode_entry */,
#endif
    int         /* modifier */
);
```

`KeyCode` is a `typedef` from `X.h`

```
typedef unsigned char KeyCode;
```

so I guess `narrow` here, referes to the width of the type used for `KeyCode`.

The same construct for the same `typedef` can be found in other files, for example `XKBlib.h`

Comment: Thanks! So *narrow prototype* is not C language lingo in general, but refers to X11 specific widths of certain types like `KeyCode`.

Answer (score 1):

Besides being noted in INSTALL, it was also an FAQ, topical for a few years [Why doesn't the scrollbar work?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#narrowproto) (also see the notes in the change-log during [2006](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.log.html#xterm_209))

Comment: Thomas, I realize you are the xterm maintainer. If this is (was) an FAQ, on Cygwin the default configure options use narrow prototypes. Is it possible to change the configure script to use the proper (working) options when run on Cygwin? Looking at the configure script for xterm-314, line 14682, it explicitly sets cf_default_narrowproto=yes for `*cygwin*`, when it should be no to work out-of-the-box.

Comment: I suppose so - I had set the defaults based on the imake configuration -- note that the revision date for the macro is in 2006.  Since 2006, it's possible that someone changed the default configuration for cygwin-x